# Ventana en Batch

Tags: batch

quiero hacer una ventana de broma en la que parezca que estoy desencriptando  algo, pero quiero que el bloque de binario para en cierto punto para que sea legible lo de "descencriptando" 
Además me gustaría hacer que los unos y ceros cambiaran constantemente entre ellos.

```
  echo off
  color 2
echo descencriptando...
:star
echo1010101011101000100110001001010111011000000001111110101001010100101010101
goto start
```

PD: ese binario no significa nada, solo lo escribí al azar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     echo off
  color 2

goto :a
:a
cls
echo descencriptando...
echo 01010011 01001001 01010011 01010100 01000101 01001101 01000001 
echo 00100000 01000010 01001001 01001110 01000001 01010010 01001001 
echo 01001111 01000101 01101110 01110100 01110010 01100101 00100000 
echo 01110100 01101111 01100100 01101111 01110011 00100000 01101100 
echo 01101111 01110011 00100000 01110011 01101001 01110011 01110100 
echo 01100101 01101101 01100001 01110011 00100000 01100100 01100101 
echo 00100000 01101110 01110101 01101101 01100101 01110010 01100001 
echo 01100011 01101001 11000011 10110011 01101110 00100000 01110101 
echo 01110011 01100001 01100100 01101111 01110011 00100000 01110000 
echo 01010011 01001001 01010011 01010100 01000101 01001101 01000001 
echo 00100000 01000010 01001001 01001110 01000001 01010010 01001001 
echo 01001111 01000101 01101110 01110100 01110010 01100101 00100000 
echo 01110100 01101111 01100100 01101111 01110011 00100000 01101100 
echo 01101111 01110011 00100000 01110011 01101001 01110011 01110100 
echo 01100101 01101101 01100001 01110011 00100000 01100100 01100101 
echo 00100000 01101110 01110101 01101101 01100101 01110010 01100001 
echo 01100011 01101001 11000011 10110011 01101110 00100000 01110101 
echo 01110011 01100001 01100100 01101111 01110011 00100000 01110000 
echo 01010011 01001001 01010011 01010100 01000101 01001101 01000001 
echo 00100000 01000010 01001001 01001110 01000001 01010010 01001001 
echo 01001111 01000101 01101110 01110100 01110010 01100101 00100000 
echo 01110100 01101111 01100100 01101111 01110011 00100000 01101100 
echo 01101111 01110011 00100000 01110011 01101001 01110011 01110100 
echo 01100101 01101101 01100001 01110011 00100000 01100100 01100101 
echo 00100000 01101110 01110101 01101101 01100101 01110010 01100001 
echo 01100011 01101001 11000011 10110011 01101110 00100000 01110101 
echo 01110011 01100001 01100100 01101111 01110011 00100000 01110000 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
:b
cls
echo descencriptando...
echo 1101100 00101100 00100000 01110001 01110101 01100101 00100000 
echo 01100101 01101101 01110000 01101100 01100101 01100001 00100000 
echo 01100100 01101001 01100101 01111010 00100000 01100011 01101001 
echo 01100110 01110010 01100001 01110011 00100000 01101111 00100000 
echo 01100100 11000011 10101101 01100111 01101001 01110100 01101111 
echo 01110011 00101110 00100000 01000101 00100000 01110100 01110010 
echo 01100001 01110100 01100001 00100000 01100100 01100101 01101100 
echo 00100000 01110011 01101001 01110011 01110100 01100101 01101101 
echo 01100001 00100000 01110001 01110101 01100101 00100000 01110100 
echo 1101100 00101100 00100000 01110001 01110101 01100101 00100000 
echo 01100101 01101101 01110000 01101100 01100101 01100001 00100000 
echo 01100100 01101001 01100101 01111010 00100000 01100011 01101001 
echo 01100110 01110010 01100001 01110011 00100000 01101111 00100000 
echo 01100100 11000011 10101101 01100111 01101001 01110100 01101111 
echo 01110011 00101110 00100000 01000101 00100000 01110100 01110010 
echo 01100001 01110100 01100001 00100000 01100100 01100101 01101100 
echo 00100000 01110011 01101001 01110011 01110100 01100101 01101101 
echo 01100001 00100000 01110001 01110101 01100101 00100000 01110100 
echo 1101100 00101100 00100000 01110001 01110101 01100101 00100000 
echo 01100101 01101101 01110000 01101100 01100101 01100001 00100000 
echo 01100100 01101001 01100101 01111010 00100000 01100011 01101001 
echo 01100110 01110010 01100001 01110011 00100000 01101111 00100000 
echo 01100100 11000011 10101101 01100111 01101001 01110100 01101111 
echo 01110011 00101110 00100000 01000101 00100000 01110100 01110010 
echo 01100001 01110100 01100001 00100000 01100100 01100101 01101100 
echo 00100000 01110011 01101001 01110011 01110100 01100101 01101101 
echo 01100001 00100000 01110001 01110101 01100101 00100000 01110100 
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
goto a
```